# Javascript img to base64 don't load

Tags: javascript, canvas, base64, photoshop-script

I develop **Photoshop extension** that sends images to the server.

**Edit:** Extensions in photoshop build from **html** file that define the GUI, **js** file that basically is the same as any js file, but it's can also launch photoshop function and it is **execute from photoshop.**

I need to send the images from the file system of the user (from C:\path\to\images)

To encode the images I converted them to dataURL (base64).

**The problem** occurs in the first time that I convert the images to dataURL. But in the second time and so, it manages to convert the images and everything is fine. In the first time the image doesn't loaded.

I have a folder where the images are and I want to upload the pictures from there, I used a loop that runs on photos and set them into `<img src=path>` to and then it converts them based 64 via `<canvas>`.

My code:

```
function convertLayersToBase64(imgHeight, imgWidth){
    var img = new Image();
    images = [];
    for (var i=0; i<=imagesLength; i++){
        path = folder + "layer " + i +".png";
        img.src = path;
        var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        canvas.height = imgHeight;
        canvas.width = imgWidth;
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0); 
        var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
        images.push( dataURL );
    }
    return images;
}
```

I tried to delay the conversion by delay:

```
function delay(time) {
    var d1 = new Date();
    var d2 = new Date();
    while (d2.valueOf() < d1.valueOf() + time) {
        d2 = new Date();
    }
}
```

JQuery when ready:

```
$(function(){
    images.push(getBase64Image());
});
```

Img.complete

```
while(!img.complete)
    continue;
```

(In the last example the code stuck in loop)

To put the function in:

```
img.onload = function(){
    //the function here..
    //when I use this method it succeed to convert
    //only the last image.
}
```

Nothing worked.. 
I tried everything, please tell me what to change and how to fix that.

**Edit:** It's seem to me that the only way to load an image it's when the code

Comment: You should use a FileReader instead of a canvas to encode a file to a base64 dataURI. Then if you really want to use the canvas, you have to wait that your image has loaded before being able to draw it on the canvas.

Comment: @Kaiido I didn't manage to create a new file that can read image from local, `var f = new File(path);` seem not to work.

Comment: No, I talked about a [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL). But be careful though, it is also asynchronous. Oh sorry I didn't read your code carefully enough, only the "*I want to upload **your** pictures from there*". But since it comes from your server, you'll also need to use [XHR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) and its `responseType = 'blob'` property setting in order to use the FileReader (still better than canvas conversion).

Comment: @Kaiido I need to read file from the file system of the user, I know that there is problem with this, but I still managed to load img from file system (the problem is that it's worh only on the second time). FileReader should work?

Comment: You mean from a file path, like `C:/UserFolder/something` ??? That shouldn't not even work from a second attempt !

Comment: @Kaiido yes, file path, and it's work for me just in the second attempt. Maybe it's different in photoshop? The extension build from **html** file that define the GUI, **js** file that basically is the same as any js file, but it can also launch photoshop function. Now I tried the same function in chrome, and I get an error about tainted canvas.

Comment: Yes that's the most unclear part of your question, maybe causing all the comments and answers irrelevant. Where are you executing this script exactly? Is this from PS or from browser? If from PS, I won't be able to help you much as I didn't even know PS had support for html canvas... Anyway, please [edit] your question including this major detail.

Comment: @Kaiido Thank you.. I edited the question. the sciprt is executing from photoshop.

Comment: @Kaiido You may still be able to help me.. In [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qfcsmnk4/) I have the relevant code, and when I use btn1 the first time, nothing happen, but in the second time and and so there is an error about tainted canvas. I used the chrome debugger. Why it's happen only in the second time and so??

Answer (score 0):

The function `onload` is an asynchronous action. You cannot just return `images` as the last statement within your `convertLayersToBase64` function. You should either use `promises`, or a more simple approach would be to use a `callback` function.

```
function convertLayersToBase64(imgHeight, imgWidth, callback){
    var images = [];
    for (var i = 0; i <= imagesLength; i++) {
         var img = new Image();
         img.onload = function() {
            var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            canvas.height = imgHeight;
            canvas.width = imgWidth;
            var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0); 
            var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
            images.push(dataURL);
            if(images.length === imagesLength) {
               callback(images);
            }
        }

        path = folder + "layer " + i +".png";
        img.src = path;
    }
}
```

You would call this like:

```
convertLayersToBase64(200, 200, function(images) {
     console.log('hii, i got images', images);
});
```

This is obviously without any form of error check, or even best practice guidelines, but I'll leave it up to you to implement that.

Comment: thank you for the quick answer.. I add `if(images.length === imagesLength) {alert("finish all images");}` to my code, and nothing happen. it's convert only the last image.

Comment: Don't declare a variable in a for loop like that, it will reference the one of the last iteration in the async callback. Either use `this` in the event handler, either use a forEach iterator.

Comment: @Kaiido damn :) you are right. I know it's bad practice like this, but i was so sure there were no variables from the for loop in the onload function. But there is a sneak `img` variable. I've updated my answer

Comment: This Q&A is a many-time duplicate. Better to close the question than create yet another duplicate.